# What is the proper way to thank someone?

Tags: discussion, protocol

I was about to thank a person for a good comment. And then, in greyed-out text, it seemed to say that I shouldn't write, "Thanks bro" (or some other similar action).

What then is the proper SE-sanctioned way of voicing thanks for a good post or comment (besides the voting) if I can't just simply say, "thanks"?

Comment: If we all thanked one another for good comments, the pages would become very cluttered. Then again, if 'thanks' is permitted then 'no thanks' has to be also permitted. Then the pages become _twice_ as cluttered. And arguments would  break out. The site is academic and 'thanks' is stated by up-voting the contributions. 'No thanks' is stated by a down-vote. I am referring, here, to questions and answers which is what drives the site and provides a disciplined archive for academic reference. Comments may be deleted at any time for many reasons.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to thank people like that, but make sure you've voted on their post. If you are really thankful for one post in particular, you could make a bounty to give them an extra reward.